# Is it possible to configure rsyslog with two spool files?

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

Is it possible to configure rsyslog with two spool files or is it possible to separate the spool configuration to two different file locations based on a certain logic?

Comment: Could you please give example?

Comment: Not sure I understand, the question is the example.